# how to delete records from database with an Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I am using php,mysql and ajax to delete record from a table. The problem is that the in MySQL_query it not getting the id it shows "id= undefined", i tried to pass the id to the query but i don't know where i went wrong i tried to print MySQL its shows

```
delete from 9xx WHERE id = undefinedArray
(
    [rowid] => undefined
    [supplier] => 9xx
)
```

can anyone tell me how to pass the id ...thanks

**My ajax**

```
$(".deletesuppliernetwork").live('click',function()
        {
         arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
        var supplier=document.getElementById("supplier").value;

        if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update?"))
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "suppliernetwork/delete.php",
        data: "rowid="+arr[2]+"&supplier="+supplier,
        success: function(data){
                                                         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                                                         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                                    }});
        }
        });
```

My html

```
<?php
include"db.php";

$supplier_id=$_GET['supplier_id'];

if($supplier_id!=""){

$sql=mysql_query("select * from $supplier_id order by country,networkname" );

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo '  <td style="width:123px" class="edit supplier '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["supplier"].'</td>
                <td style="width:104px" class="edit rn '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["rn"].'</td>    
            <td style="width:103px" class="edit sc '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["sc"].'</td>    
            <td style="width:108px" class="edit comment '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["comment"].'</td>

            <td style="width:62px" class="deletesuppliernetwork '.$rows["id"].'"><img   src="/image/delete.png" style="margin:0 0 0 17px" ></td>                                

        </tr>';


}
}
?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
    include"db.php";

$supplier=$_POST['supplier'];




        $rownum=$_POST['rowid'];  
        $sql="delete from $supplier WHERE id = ".$rownum."";

        print $sql;

        mysql_query($sql);  


    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td style="width:62px" class="deletesuppliernetwork '.$rows["id"].'"><img   src="/image/delete.png" style="margin:0 0 0 17px" ></td>
```

the index of your ID is 1, that is second index. not 2.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "suppliernetwork/delete.php",
        data: "rowid="+arr[1]+"&supplier="+supplier,
        success: function(data){
                                                         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                                                         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                                    }});
```

Comment: thanks its worked but i want to hide the 'td' when its deleted.i think its after sucess

Comment: see the second answer by me, it will hide the row without needing to reload the complete page

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowObj = $(this);    
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "suppliernetwork/delete.php",
            data: "rowid="+arr[1]+"&supplier="+supplier,
            success: function(data){
                 $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                 $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                  $(rowObj).parents("tr:first").hide();
            }});
```

this should hide your complete row.

Comment: @arokia Please the updat above `$(this).parents("tr:first").hide();`

Comment: when you are in the Success block, **this** would change to local scope, create variable as above updated answer. :)