# How to delete a saved row in mysql database after clicking on a 'exit' button

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I currently have an upload button that saves all types of files to a mysql table.
I have an exit button that I want to delete the currently uploaded files if clicked.
NOTE: all files uploaded on current page has same referenceID so the query is as easy as saying delete all from table where id=id..

Here is the button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="exit" style="float:left;
   class="buttonLW" href="https://BACK-LINK">exit
</button>
```

Here is the php delete query (suedo code):

```
if ($submitButton === "delete-new") { 

    $query15 ="DELETE * FROM table WHERE id='{$id}'";

}
```

my question, is the button aloud to use this sort of format? am I allowed to say 
if ($submitButton === "delete-new") without using a form?

How can I go about deleting the currently saved files with same id after clicking my exit button.

Comment: Sidenote: ID's must be unique, as opposed to a class where elements can each contain the same.

Comment: all ids are unique, I have 1 table for uploads that corresponds to the main table which is connected through its id.

Comment: so you can have 1 report with a unique id, but many uploads with that correspond to that id

Comment: *"NOTE: all files uploaded on current page has same ID"* why is that?

Comment: yes, the uploads do indeed have same id, but its more of a referenceid

Comment: They shouldn't be. Why would you want that? It'll only cause problems, which you're faced with now.

Comment: because I have 2 tables, the main table has a unique id, the second table is the table that has all the uploaded files.  That table has a unique id for each uploaded file BUT ALSO has a referenceid that is the same as the unique id from the main table.  I do this because you can uploaded many files for that 1 session for that unique id from the main table.

Comment: You could most likely achieve this using Ajax then.

Comment: onclick call an ajax function, then call a php file which deletes from database?

Comment: Yep, that ought to do it.

Comment: so the issue i had with that was I dont know how to redirect the exit button if its a <button> instead of a <a> with a href

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/19208862/ for an example. Plus, if you Google "delete from database using ajax php" you will find many other results.

Comment: To redirect is another issue. You'll need to use a header for that, or a meta tag. Ajax/PHP will probably take care of that also. You'll need to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Upfront, the `style` value isn't terminated, you're missing the closing quote `"`.

If you get `$submitButton` with

```
$submitButton = $_POST['submit'];
```

you can compare it that way, but the value will be `exit` and not `delete-new`. So you must rather say

```
if ($submitButton === 'exit') {
    // ...
}
```

or change `value="exit"` to `value="delete-new"`.

Which leads to the next point, the delete statement. The [`delete`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) statement must look like

```
delete from mytable WHERE id = '$id'
```

But don't do it this way, because this is unsafe and invites all sorts of SQL injection.
Better use [prepared statments](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), e.g.

```
delete from mytable WHERE id = ?
```

and bind `$id` when you execute the prepared statement.